# ios17, html file input capture, photos privacy options

Tags: gps, metadata, jpeg, ios17, ios-privacy-settings

__ RESOLVED
visited apple store tested on iphone14 , ios17 with location on for camera / safari

photos selected from the photoroll will bring up the options menu and will preserve the embedded metadata ( exif/GPS )
BUT, using the "chooser" to select the camera and take a new photo to be uploaded... this still results in removal of embedded metadata..

see https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207088#c26
__

still confused over "new options" dialog in ios17 intended to allow INCLUSION of metadata ( EXIF / GPS ) in the context of webapp with html such as:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg" capture />
```

Prior to 17 , ios & safari would default to removal of any metadata including EXIF / GPS when a html webpage using the control above where the UI + input control grabs the camera, capturing a photo for upload by either a form or scripted fetch.POST() .

### ios17 rel notes cover "picker api" and photos taken, selected under installed app context where a new "options" choice allows add-hoc or one time control over whether to include/remove photo location and other meta data.

see photo at bottom... "options" menu in extreme low-left side

IMO - rel 17 did not change anything here?? There is NOT a new "OPTIONS" dialog that shows up in connection with the context of a general, html chooser via file.input.type="jpeg", grabbing the camera for an image to be taken  and then uploaded when the stack is a webpage with html in control ( not an  app where granting of privacy is different ).

On ios17 / iphone 14, i tested :

> https://mutiny.cz/exifr

for capture, for upload, for retention of metadata ( gps )

toggle off ALL options then, select both EXIF, GPS

use the file picker in upper left to select camera , take photo , upload , parse metadata

results:

ios 17 still is removes metadata, does not pop up an options dialog allowing a choice for " preserve location " . The output on the linked page is blank for GPS - the metadata was removed by safari .

android devices on chrome browser work fine and you see the GPS data listed in the output from the ./exifr page on mutiny domain.

did i miss something in settings on ios17?
location is ON.  camera has location priviledges

I had thought that changes to ios under picker/ private access to photos...
might then display  ‘Options’ button dialog allowing to remove metadata OR KEEP METADATA from photo just taken???

OR is privacy restriction such that i need to operate under the context of an installed app in order to utilize the new privacy controls allowing inclusion of gps/exif on upload of a just-captured photo?

[image]